# Alternative to using Object and casting in a map

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following class which represents a set of properties.

```
public class Properties
{
    /** String type properties. */
    private final List<String> m_stringProperties = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3");

    /** Float type properties. */
    private final List<String> m_floatProperties = Arrays.asList("float1", "float2", "float3");

    /** Integer type properties. */
    private final List<String> m_intProperties = Arrays.asList("int1", "int2");

    public class PropertyType
    {
        private final String m_name;
        private final Object m_value;

        public PropertyType(String name, Object value)
        {
            m_name = name;
            m_value = value;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return m_name;
        }

        public Object getValue()
        {
            return m_value;
        }
    }

    /** The container for the properties. */
    private final Map<String, PropertyType> m_properties = new HashMap<>();

    public PropertyType getProperty(String name)
    {
        return m_properties.get(name);
    }

    public void setProperty(String name, Object value)
    {
        if ((m_stringProperties.contains(name) && value instanceof String)
                || (m_floatProperties.contains(name) && value instanceof Float)
                || (m_intProperties.contains(name) && value instanceof Integer))
        {
            m_properties.put(name, new PropertyType(name, value));
        }

        else
        {
            assert false : "Invalid property name";
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes**

1. Each property has a name and a value.
2. Property values can be of type String, Float or Integer.
3. The names of properties is restricted to the values defined in the list at the top of the class.
4. A given property can only be added to the map if it is the correct type for that property name.

The class could be used as follows:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

// set properties
properties.setProperty("str1", "testId");
properties.setProperty("float1", 1.0f);

// get properties
Properties.PropertyType str1 = properties.getProperty("str1");
Properties.PropertyType float1 = properties.getProperty("float1");
Properties.PropertyType invalid = properties.getProperty("unknown");    // return null

System.out.println("str1: " + str1.getValue());
System.out.println("float1: " + float1.getValue());

float f1 = (float) properties.getProperty("float1").getValue();
Object o1 = properties.getProperty("float1").getValue();

System.out.println("f1: " + f1);
System.out.println("o1: " + o1);

properties.setProperty("str1", 1.0f);       // assertion - str1 property should be String, not Float
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to implement this. Specifically, I'd like to avoid the use of `Object` and the casting that goes with it. I've experimented with a parametrised class and generic types and even a typesafe heterogenous container as described in Item 20 of Effective Java.

I would like to make it as typesafe as possible - i.e. enforce type checking by the compiler - so that if `getProperty` is called the return value is automatically the correct type.

I realise that I could overload `setProperty` for each type and that `getProperty` could just return an `Object` instead of the nested type `PropertyType` but that would still leave me with a container of `<String, Object>`.

I'm a Java newbie coming from C++. In C++ the map value would be a `boost::variant`.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the class will receive one of the 3 types, and the Compiler will acuse that, you can use some Polymorphism.

Example:

```
public PropertyType(String name, String value)
        {
            m_name = name;
            m_value = value;
        }

 public PropertyType(String name, Integer value)
        {
            m_name = name;
            m_value = value;
        }

 public PropertyType(String name, Float value)
        {
            m_name = name;
            m_value = value;
        }
```

The String,Integer and Float extends Object, so you don't need to cast they to the variable `private final Object m_value;`

But if you need to check the type of the variable in execution type (For example, create and variable and don't know if it's some of the three types) this may not work.